# Apply label according to the value in the row

Tags: python, pandas, function

My Dataframe looks like this:

| * | C1 | C2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-03-31 | -4.176624103220332 | 10.364548764470144 |
| 2005-06-30 | 1.4269361408926793 | -3.8354764326157116 |
| 2005-09-30 | 5.483776533348614 | 10.1320224598959638 |
| 2005-12-31 | -11.636063047222431 | 1.5870493058713961 |

I want check value row by row and apply label as follows:

```
if Rate of change > 10 then 'rising'
elif Rate of change < 10 then 'falling'
else 'constant'
```

And Output should be like this:

| * | C1 | C2 | C1_rate | C2_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2005-03-31 | -4.176624103220332 | 10.364548764470144 | constant | rising |
| 2005-06-30 | 1.4269361408926793 | -3.8354764326157116 | constant | constant |
| 2005-09-30 | 5.483776533348614 | 10.1320224598959638 | constant | rising |
| 2005-12-31 | -11.636063047222431 | 1.5870493058713961 | falling | constant |

I tried with following code:

```
def check_rate(x):
    if x >= 10:
        return 'rising'
    elif x <= -10:
        return 'falling'   
    elif x > -10 and x < 10:
        return 'constant'

for col in df.columns:
    df[col+'_rate'] = df[col].apply(check_rate)
```

But, It doesn't return the expected value and the first row shows NaN

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When I copy your df and run your code, I get the expected output. Have you updated to the latest version of pandas?

Answer (score 0):

```
def classify(x):
    if x>=10:
        return "raising"
    elif x<=-10:
        return "faling"
    elif x > -10 and x < 10:
        return 'constant'
for col in ["C1", "C2"]:
    df[f"{col}_rate"] = df[col].apply(classify)
df
```